# Url changes when posting

Tags: node.js

I have this html:

```
<form action="/Home/Insert" method="POST" name="form1">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="Name"/>
    <br/>
    Price:
    <input type="text" name="Price"/>
    <br/>
    <button id="btnPost">Post Data</button>
</form>
```

When the form posts, my url changes to .../Home/Insert. I don't want my url to be changed when posting, how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either redirect the client ([HTTP 3xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection), server side) or use an [AJAX request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) (user side) to keep the user on the same page.

Comment: can you show me how to redirect the client? sorry, i'm new in nodejs

Comment: Use [`response.writeHead(307,{'Location':THISPAGEURL});`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers) (replace `THISPAGEURL` ;) ) at the correct place. Since you didn't show any JS code it's hard to determine whether you're using a framework or a plain HTTP server.

Comment: I'm not using any framework. thanks Zeta, i'll try it out and tell you if it succeeds

Comment: You're welcome. It's always good to add the relevant code to the question though ;).

Comment: That's what I wanted, but it asks me if i want to redirect to the url :( thanks anyway and i'll consider adding relevant code for the future

Answer (score 1):

That's how HTTP works.
When you POST to a URL, the browser navigates to that URL.

You may want to modify the server to redirect back to the original URL after the POST.